# Handling keypress events in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

My app needs to run in a security-restricted browser. Because of this, textbox input is blocked in Silverlight (but not in HTML). I need to intercept the keystrokes and put them in the textbox to override this feature.

When a key event is detected, it returns the letters all in upper case. (Why??) I need to be able to convert a keypress to lower case but don't have access to the shift state in the KeyEventArgs. The PlatformKeyCode supposedly returns ascii (this is an English/US only app) but it doesn't detect the shift state and returns all lower-case keys in upper case. These textboxes are username and password input and are case-sensitive.

I'm having a hard time believing I can't do something as simple as get a username and password.

I have no control over the security settings of the IE browser as it runs in a separate desktop application that was written by another company. This website is designed to interface with that desktop software. The authors of the software have no idea why Silverlight text input doesn't work. The textboxes work fine in a normal browser.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Keyboard.Modifiers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.modifiers.aspx) value to determine if <kbd>shift</kbd> is pressed.

```
ModifierKeys keys = Keyboard.Modifiers;
bool shiftKey = (keys & ModifierKeys.Shift) != 0;
```

[This blog](http://www.michaelsnow.com/2010/04/29/silverlight-tip-of-the-day-8-detecting-alt-shift-control-window-apple-keys-combinations/) has additional information for this and other keys.

Note that the key press events tell you what key is pressed, not what character that key generates. There is a distinction between the two.

Comment: Jeff, thank you very much. That seems to have done the trick. Sad that I have to manually write a function that places typed characters into a textbox, but it's a solution!

Comment: @Miguel: Happy to help. Does seem strange that you can get the key events but the textbox can't receive them itself.